# How do I get a deployed contract's address using Web3.js version 4?

Tags: web3js

I am deploying a contract from a factory contract and trying to get the deployed contract's address.

Here's my code:

```
 async createContract(contract){
      let contractReceipt = null;
      const createdContract = await this.factory.methods
        .createContract(
          Math.floor(new Date(contract.expirationDate).getTime() / 1000),
          contract.task,
          contract.format,
          contract.minimalLength,
          contract.minimalResolution,
          JSON.stringify(contract.location)
        )
        .send({
          from: this.account,
          gas: await this.getGasFeeForContractCall(contract),
          value: web3Utils.toWei(contract.pay.toString(), 'ether')
        })
        .on('error', function (error, receipt) {
          console.log('createContract error', error, receipt)
          throw error
        });
      console.log(createdContract)
      const contractAddress =  await this.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(createdContract.transactionHash);
      console.log('deployed contract address', contractAddress)
      return contractReceipt.contractAddress;
    },
```

This returns an object shaped like this, with no contractAddress property.

```
blockHash
: 
"0x5a5363e76ac94147248c1eb0b96e1f7e53da3aa1d1f4f3555cbdac36402ee759"
blockNumber
: 
9329514n
cumulativeGasUsed
: 
6853814n
effectiveGasPrice
: 
173294n
from
: 
"0x500694d00efc0315cac629b83dfd11c8b038afaa"
gasUsed
: 
1519833n
logs
: 
Array(0)
length
: 
0
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
logsBloom
: 
"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
status
: 
1n
to
: 
"0xef69217db1560631ad9274cae93ae8c85a4bc6c1"
transactionHash
: 
"0x65748c906c277f458e3a49f99764cf06526c5f7703642df42d532bf3a9a6323d"
transactionIndex
: 
44n
type
: 
2n
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the contract function to return the new contract address (in solidity) or even add an event there to return the address of the new token as soon as it's deployed. if it haven't on the contract you (maybe i'm wrong) can retrieve it at all.